# PowerShell copy to $null

Tags: powershell

In Windows shell you can fetch the contents of a file and copy it to "\Device\Null" with a command like `copy c:\filename NUL`. (This is useful for recalling externally-archived files without wasting space or updating with `touch`.)

But I can't figure out how to do the same in PowerShell using `$null`, `NUL`, `\\.\NUL` and more (and I don't want to call out a separate CMD.EXE process to do this for every file).

```
PS C:\> Copy-Item -Path  .\filename -Destination NUL
Copy-Item : Cannot process path 'C:\NUL' because the the target represents a reserved device name.
At line:1 char:10
+ Copy-Item <<<<  -Path  .\filename -Destination NUL
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\NUL:String) [Copy-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CopyError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

PS C:\> Copy-Item .\filename NUL
Copy-Item : Cannot process path 'C:\NUL' because the the target represents a reserved device name.
At line:1 char:10
+ Copy-Item <<<<  .\filename NUL
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\NUL:String) [Copy-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CopyError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

PS C:\> copy .\filename '\\.\NUL'
Copy-Item : Cannot process path '\\.\NUL' because the the target represents a reserved device name.
At line:1 char:5
+ copy <<<<  .\filename '\\.\NUL'
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (\\.\NUL:String) [Copy-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CopyError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

Any other ideas how to do this?

Comment: That's because `$null` isn't a device/drive per se in Powershell. Guess `Out-Null` won't work any better. But I still don't really get what you are trying to achieve with copying to $null, can you elaborate?

Comment: Some archiving software will save the actual file data off to another remote filesystem/database/tape but leave behind a tiny stub marked with NTFS' "offline" attribute. When a user fetches the *content* of the file (not just the file attributes), the software fetches it from the archive and restores the local file. Thus... the easiest way to restore all the stubbed/offline files is to copy them somewhere--but copying to another files system takes forever (and then you have to delete all the crap), whereas copying them to NUL is faster.

Comment: Useful for Dropbox too, if you have Smart Sync set to 'Online Only'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Effectively, you just want to do a read on the file. If so, this will work:

```
Get-ChildItem .\filename | Get-Content | Out-Null
```

It's probably overkill though. You could try:

```
$File=[system.io.file]::OpenRead(".\filename")
$File.Close()
```

This just opens the file for reading (which may be enough to bring it back) and closes it again.

Comment: /me smacks forehead... Your answer makes perfect sense. Thanks, @craika!

Comment: You can also `ls *.txt | % { [system.io.file]::OpenRead($_).Close() }` to, for example, bring back all the `.txt` files.

Comment: Thumbs up for the second OpenRead option - OneDrive on demand is great but sometimes you want to force the download. Get-Content does work but does read the file in it's entirety each time - and Get-Content is inefficient for large files. The OpenRead() Close() combo forces OneDrive to download *and* runs very quickly a second time